# Change HelloSign notification email contents

Tags: php, hellosign-api

I have used Hellosign to electronically sign a PDF template uploaded there. However I could change the company name and company logo from HelloSign settings and email message body and email subject through the API when the requests are sent.

But I cannot change/ there is no way to change the text in notification emails sent by HelloSign when someone signs the document or all done signing. How can I change these? Any workarounds?

These are what I need to change in HelloSign emails

When sending sign requests,

- Company Name, Company Logo (Can be done through Settings)
- From  (Can be done through Settings) > (MY COMPANY),
- Subject (Can be done through API) > "MY COMPANY sent you a document to review and sign."
- Name of the Document (currently the email subject is automatically taken as the document name and no place to change this) > "TEST AGREEMENT FOR <*SIGNER'S NAME*>"
- Message (Can be done through API)

When someone signs the document (Just signed notification emails),

- From > "MY COMPANY"
- Subject > "You successfully signed your TEST Agreement"
- Document > "TEST Agreement for <*SIGNER'S NAME*>"

When all sign the document (Fully signed notification email),

- From > "MY COMPANY"
- Subject > "Your TEST Agreement has been completed."
- Email Body Heading (Below the tiny rounded signature image) > "Everyone has signed
  your TEST Agreement"

How can I change these in HelloSign emails? Can they be done via API?

Answer (score 0):

For information on customizing these signature request email notifications from HelloSign.com, please refer to this helpful article in our FAQs:
https://faq.hellosign.com/hc/en-us/articles/212521678-Branding

If you'd like to customize your email notifications completely, you can implement the Embedded Signing feature using the HelloSign API. With embedded signing, your users sign documents within an iFrame embedded on your site. You would send out all email notifications on your end and HelloSign doesn't send any notifications on your behalf.

For more information on the API, please take a look at our [API documentation](https://app.hellosign.com/api/documentation). HelloSign also has an [Embedded Signing Walkthrough](https://app.hellosign.com/api/embeddedSigningWalkthrough) to get you started with this workflow as well.